# need to return some data from a function using chrome.storage api

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Content.js

```
function GetFilterfromStore3(document_root) {
    var numberdata = 0;
    chrome.storage.sync.get("fiterlink", function (filterlist) {
        var links = [];
        var number = 0;
        node = document_root.getElementsByTagName("a");
        //alert(filterlist.fiterlink[0].data.link)
        for (var i = 0; i < filterlist.fiterlink.length; i++) {
            if (filterlist.fiterlink[i].data.selected == true) {
                links[i] = filterlist.fiterlink[i].data.link;
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < node.length; i++) {
            for (var j = 0; j < links.length; j++) {
                if (node[i].getAttribute("href") != null) {
                    if (node[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf(links[j]) != -1) {
                        number++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        alert(number + " :1");
        numberdata = number;

    });
    return (numberdata);
};

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    action: "getnumberoflink",
    number: GetFilterfromStore3(document),
});
```

Event.js

```
chrome.tabs.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function (activeInfo) {

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'Getnumberoflinks.js' });
    // Perform the callback when a message is received from the content script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
        if (message.action == "getnumberoflink") {
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor({ color: [255, 0, 0, 255] });

            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({ text: message.number.toString() });
        }
    });
});
```

I need to get number from content.js in event.js.
i have some filterlist in my chrome storage and after this  i am finding links count on page.
but in event.js i get 0
please help me out and comment if you have some confusion.

Comment: chrome.* API is asynchronous so chrome.storage.sync.get callback runs after the enclosing function. Rework the code and put sendMessage inside the callback.

Comment: but need to pass document element to GetFilterfromStore3 and return a number in message in event.js.
please help by giving me example

Comment: Use a standard approach for asynchronous code e.g. `Promise`. There are lots of tutorials.